# reading dbConnection.properties file in java to connect to database using eclipse

Tags: java, database

I have create a dbConnection.properties file and placed it into WEB-INF. To read that file and connect to database I hava written a class as

```
public class DbConnection {

public static Connection connection()
{
    Connection con=null;
    //String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo";
    try
    {
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("WEB-INF/dbConnection.properties"));
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();

        String drivers = prop.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
        String connectionURL = prop.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        String username = prop.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        String password = prop.getProperty("jdbc.password");

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Class.forName(drivers);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,username,password);

            System.out.println("Connection Successful");
            return con;     
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("error !!");
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Its going into catch block. How can i read .properties file?

Answer (score 3):

Place the properties file under `src` if you are using eclipse or `WEB-INF/classes` if you are using ant or gradle or any other tool for that matter and then modify the statement

```
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("WEB-INF/dbConnection.properties"));
        prop.load(in);
```

with

```
 prop.load(DbConnection.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("dbConnection.properties"));
```

Make this changes and it will work!

Comment: its giving fileNotFoundException

Comment: did you place the properties file under src folder? If you are using ant or any other tool like gradle to build then place the properties file under WEB-INF/classes and try

Comment: I have two packges under src. so the package which includes DBConnection class,I have placed this file into prjct.db package.

Comment: @Sonam Are you using eclipse? if so copy the properties file and then right click on src and then paste the file!! That is all you need to do. I will update the answer so that it would be more clear to you!